# How can I check if variable property named id?

Tags: javascript

I have variable named `t`.

Some times this variable equal to some object:

```
var t = {id:2 Name:"Mike" };
```

And some times this variable might contain only string.Like this:

```
 var t = "someString";
```

At some point I need to check if variable is object and if it contains property named `id`.

How can I check if variable is object and contains property named `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `typeof` and `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if(typeof t == 'object' && t.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
     //your code for using t.id
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `&&` (and) operator

```
if (t && t.id && td.id === "blah")
```

Or shorter:

```
if (t && t.id === "blah")
```

Comment: Is there any reason to ever use the first variant?

Comment: In this context, no... Anything that would choke on `t.id ===` won't make it past the first check.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your variable using `toString.call(value) === '[object Object]'` and `toString.call(value) === '[object String]'`

```js
var t = {
  id: 2,
  Name: "Mike"
};

function isObject(value, property) {
  return value !== null && toString.call(value) === '[object Object]' && value.hasOwnProperty(property);
}

function isString(value) {
  return value !== null && toString.call(value) === '[object String]';
}

document.write("isObject : " + isObject(t, 'id') + " | " + "isString : " + isString(t) + "<br>");

var t = "blabla";

document.write("isObject : " + isObject(t, 'id') + " | " + "isString : " + isString(t));
```